# Ionic 4, trying to show 2 per row with col-6, it still puts too many per row

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

After searching several stack overflow and other posts I figured the proper way to get two "Cards" or anything really (I've tried with just text or paragraphs or simpler things to card) to show per row was to repeat with a col-6 on the same row and it should wrap:

```
  <ion-grid>
      <ion-row>
        <ion-col col-6 *ngFor="let place of places">
          <ion-card>
            <ion-card-content>
              <ion-card-title>
                Card's Title
              </ion-card-title>
              <p>
                Card's description
              </p>
            </ion-card-content>
          </ion-card>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row> 
  </ion-grid>
```

But this produces the result: [image]

Comment: Just tried your *ngFor that was working fine for me so can you please create sample here https://stackblitz.com

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-y5jw1l

Comment: I attempted to make one for Ionic 4 but am running into issues with dependencies. Aaron, I looked at yours and compared it to mine, different results. I think the big issues is Ionic 3 vs Ionic 4. I made a stock Ionic 4 and tried to upload it. https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-v1fbbh but I can't install the dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reason is because ionic 4 not use col-size anymore. Instead you should try size="6" size-sm.

https://beta.ionicframework.com/docs/layout/grid#stacked-to-horizontal